# urlencode an array of values

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to urlencode an dictionary in python with urllib.urlencode. The problem is, I have to encode an array.

The result needs to be:

```
criterias%5B%5D=member&criterias%5B%5D=issue
#unquoted: criterias[]=member&criterias[]=issue
```

But the result I get is:

```
criterias=%5B%27member%27%2C+%27issue%27%5D
#unquoted: criterias=['member',+'issue']
```

I have tried several things, but I can't seem to get the right result.

```
import urllib
criterias = ['member', 'issue']
params = {
    'criterias[]': criterias,
}
print urllib.urlencode(params)
```

If I use `cgi.parse_qs` to decode a correct query string, I get this as result:

```
{'criterias[]': ['member', 'issue']}
```

But if I encode that result, I get a wrong result back. Is there a way to produce the expected result?

Comment: `cig.parse_qs` is deprecated (only retained for backward compatibility), so it may be better to use `urlparse.parse_qs`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I only used it for comparison, so it's not really used.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The solution is far simpler than the ones listed above.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> params = {'criterias[]': ['member', 'issue']}
>>> 
>>> print urllib.urlencode(params, True)
criterias%5B%5D=member&criterias%5B%5D=issue
```

Note the True.  See http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode the doseq variable.

As a side note, you do not need the [] for it to work as an array (which is why urllib does not include it). This means that you do not not need to add the [] to all your array keys.

Comment: If you don't add the [], php will only use criterias=issue, and will ignore the "member"

Comment: Also see the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: To clarify, Python doesn't care if the `[]`'s are there: it will convert it correctly regardless. But yes, PHP (and maybe other languages?) does care, so if you have an external dependency on such systems, it is best to leave the `[]`'s... it just looks weird in Python.

Comment: Amazing. I was *sure* this was going to be difficult!

Comment: In Python 3 the `urllib` module has been broken up and the `urlencode` entry is in the `parse` submodule.  The docs are now at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode

Answer (score 12):

You can use a list of key-value pairs (tuples):

```
>>> urllib.urlencode([('criterias[]', 'member'), ('criterias[]', 'issue')])
'criterias%5B%5D=member&criterias%5B%5D=issue'
```

Comment: Well, it's very easy to write a function that transforms the dict with lists into a list of tuples.

Comment: just a note for others, to generate the urlencoded string straight from a regular dict, all you need to do is `urllib.urlencode(d.items())`

Comment: You don't even need to do that, `urllib.urlencode(d)` should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

To abstract this out to work for any parameter dictionary and convert it into a list of tuples:

```
import urllib

def url_encode_params(params={}):
    if not isinstance(params, dict): 
        raise Exception("You must pass in a dictionary!")
    params_list = []
    for k,v in params.items():
        if isinstance(v, list): params_list.extend([(k, x) for x in v])
        else: params_list.append((k, v))
    return urllib.urlencode(params_list)
```

Which should now work for both the above example as well as a dictionary with some strings and some arrays as values:

```
criterias = ['member', 'issue']
params = {
    'criterias[]': criterias,
}
url_encode_params(params)
>>'criterias%5B%5D=member&criterias%5B%5D=issue'
```

Answer (score 2):

Listcomp of values:

```
>>> criterias = ['member', 'issue']
>>> urllib.urlencode([('criterias[]', i) for i in criterias])
'criterias%5B%5D=member&criterias%5B%5D=issue'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

as aws api defines its get url: `params.0=foo&params.1=bar`

however, the disadvantage is that you need to write code to encode and decode by your own, the result is: params=[foo, bar]