# How do I accept an array as an ASP.NET MVC controller action parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an ASP.net MVC controller called `Designs` that has an action with the following signature:

```
public ActionResult Multiple(int[] ids)
```

However, when I try to navigate to this action using the url:

```
http://localhost:54119/Designs/Multiple?ids=24041,24117
```

The `ids` parameter is always null. Is there any way to get MVC to convert the `?ids=` URL query parameter into an array for the action? I've seen talk of using an action filter but as far as I can tell that will only work for POSTs where the array is passed in the request data rather than in the URL itself.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

The default model binder expects this url:

```
http://localhost:54119/Designs/Multiple?ids=24041&ids=24117
```

in order to successfully bind to:

```
public ActionResult Multiple(int[] ids)
{
    ...
}
```

And if you want this to work with comma separated values you could write a custom model binder:

```
public class IntArrayModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value
            .AttemptedValue
            .Split(',')
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then you could apply this model binder to a particular action argument:

```
public ActionResult Multiple([ModelBinder(typeof(IntArrayModelBinder))] int[] ids)
{
    ...
}
```

or apply it globally to all integer array parameters in your `Application_Start` in `Global.asax`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(int[]), new IntArrayModelBinder());
```

and now your controller action might look like this:

```
public ActionResult Multiple(int[] ids)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was missing `[FromUri]`.  `public ActionResult Multiple([FromUri]int[] ids) {}` **(GET)**

Comment: @Darin is there a way to apply the custom binding globally but just ignore for specific action?  I couldn't find a way to do that :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379040/how-to-override-global-model-binder-for-speacific-post-action-mvc5

Answer (score 18):

To extend on [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508310/2033557), something you can get away with is accepting a simple `string` in your URL parameter and converting it to an array yourself:

```
public ActionResult Multiple(string ids){
  int[] idsArray = ids.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
  /* ...process results... */
}
```

If you get a parse error while doing this (because someone passed you a malformed array), you can cause your exception handler to return a `400 Bad Request` error instead of the default, more unfriendly `404 Not Found` error that MVC returns when an endpoint is not found.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use this URL format, and ASP.NET MVC will do everything for you. But, remember to apply URL encoding.

```
?param1[0]=3344&param1[1]=2222
```

Answer (score 8):

**.Net Core Answer**

For those coming here in recent times, you can do this in .Net Core with:

```
http://localhost:54119/Designs/Multiple?ids=24041&ids=24117
```

and:

```
public ActionResult Multiple([FromQuery] int[] ids)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know where Groky's URL string was coming from, but I had the same problem with some javascript calling my controller/action. It would build up a URL of `null`, 1, or many "IDs" from a multiple-select list (which is unique to the solution I'm going to share).

I copy/pasted Darin's custom model binder and decorated my action/parameter, but it didn't work. I still got `null` valued `int[] ids`. Even in the "safe" case where I actually did have many IDs.

I ended up changing the javascript to produce an ASP.NET MVC friendly parameter array like

```
?ids=1&ids=2
```

I had to do some silly stuff, though

```
ids || []                 #=> if null, get an empty array
[ids || []]               #=> if a single item, wrap it in an array
[].concat.apply([], ...)  #=> in case I wrapped an array, flatten it
```

So, the full block was

```
ids = [].concat.apply([], [ids || []])
id_parameter = 'ids=' + ids.join('&ids=')
```

It's messy, but it's the first time I had to hack like this in javascript.

Comment: Just curious if there's a missing 'not' before "first time" in that last sentence. Otherwise, lucky you!

Comment: @DCShannon: haha, I see your point! But, this was my first time. I'm not sure if this kind of thing is normal or if I'm going overboard.