# What is dirty update in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know what will happen if I pass a query string parameter which will have the same name as a control on the form from view to controller?

From where the controller will pick the value:
A. From control ()
B. From query string(?firstname=somename)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this via a post or a get?

Comment: Why not test it yourself and see what values you get back?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanting to submit a value to a controller action method parameter.

There are two things to consider here:
1) What name/value pairs will the browser submit to the server?
2) From the set of submitted name/value pairs (where the same name may appear twice, but with two different values), which value will the controller use to populate the parameter?

For concern #1, the browser will submit all form values to the server. Both name value pairs will be submitted. Possibly one in the query string, and one in the POSTed data.

For concern #2, which value will the server use when populating the parameter of the action method...It will likely use the first one encountered in the name/value collection passed to the model binder. Short answer is that you can't tell which one will be used.

By the way, you can set up your action method parameter to [receive both values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508265/how-do-i-accept-an-array-as-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-action-parameter) ...But, I'm assuming that this isn't the functionality you're after.

I would recommend using a different name in the query string in order to avoid ambiguity.