# how to pass an array from angularjs service to web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, asp.net-web-api2

In my angular service , i am sending data to API controller as follow.

The only problem here is `StudentIds`, `value does not pass to the web API controller`.  But i am able to get values for `Date` and `Status`. Only issue is with StudentIds as i am sending an array of StudentIds.

How i can resolve this issue?

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('download', _apiUrl + 'GetStudentReport', { date: date, status: status, StudentIds: StudentIds });
```

API Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetStudentReport")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetStudentReport(DateTime date, bool status, [FromUri] Guid[] StudentIds )
{

}
```

Comment: Please provide full code . Controllers hierarchy etc.

Comment: controllers hierarchy?? Which hierarchy?

Comment: angular controller hierarchy  in your html

Comment: you are broadcasting an event 'download' but where you catch it in your code ?

Comment: `$rootScope.$broadcast` should has an handler function somewhere such as `$rootScope.$on('download',function{// handle event here})`

Comment: in download the uri constructed like this.https://localhost:12340/api/Reports/GetStudentReport?date=2015-11-12&localClientTime=2015-11-27 16:03:23&status=false&StudentIds=e0f54905-b091-e511-830c-303a64efb676,def54905-b091-e511-830c-303a64efb676

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are a special case with MVC , you have to pass it in a specific way for the controller to recreate it from the URL .

Take a look at this .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508310/2794980

You will have to write a custom model binder if your url is not in this format.

SomeActionName/?StudentIds=1&StudentIds=2