# How to pass some pair of values in MVC Core action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'd like to pass a list of parameters in an action.

I would like to use Tuple, but I saw on the internet that's not possible.

I'm building a search action which will search into many fields of an object.

So I need to pass in parameter to my action, some pair of values like below :

```
Row0 : "Name,Chris"
Row1 : "City, NY"
```

The query will return every objects in my table which have name = Chris and city = NY

Here is my action :

```
[HttpGet("objects/searchMultiple/{type}/{operateur}/{param}", Name = "searchMultiple")]
public IActionResult SearchMultiple(string type, string operator, What_To_Put_Here?)
{
   //call of the function which will execute the query with all parameters.
}
```

Comment: did you ever hear modelbinder you can create your custom query parameter type.

Comment: No, I'm beginner in Asp.Net. Thanks I will search

Comment: your welcome :) you can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508265/how-do-i-accept-an-array-as-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-action-parameter

Comment: Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel you might want to check out [OData](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+api+odata). Using that your action returns an IQueryable and the query is created and passed by the client in the URL.

Comment: You can use a Dictionary<string,string>.. or you could create a class to hold your params. If you know on which fields you are filtering having a type makes more sense and I guess you can change the client which is sending the request, to comply with this format. But maybe I'm wrong..

Comment: If I pass a dictionnary as action parameter, could you give me an exemple of the Get Request?

Comment: Can you show us how you are making the request? Is it from javascript, angular or something like that?

Comment: I'm just testing with "Postman" a chrome plugin. Actually I'm wondering how I'll pass parameters in the  get for the dictionnary

Comment: My get is like that : 
http://localhost/api/objects/searchMultiple/contact/and/{dictionnary_params}
  Where "contact" and "and" are other parameters

Comment: And to execute the request i'll use jquery

Comment: So you could pass and/city="NY"&name="john", and bind that to a class with the same properties. The framework will do the mapping for you.

Comment: Yes but I need multiple fields ^^ Because in my database I have dynamic objects, with dynamic column( in a JSON) So I can't guess what fields my users will decide to search in. So this is why I need to pass multiple pairs of values. Like
[name,Chris], [city,NY], [age,40]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146758/discussion-between-jpgrassi-and-vincent-ducroquet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
[HttpGet("objects/searchMultiple/{type}/{operateur}", Name = "searchMultiple")]
public IActionResult SearchMultiple(string type, string operateur, Dictionary<String,String> parameters)
```

And the GET request

```
http://localhost/api/objects/searchMultiple/contact/and?parameters[mail]=gmail&parameters[name]=Chris
```

Then in the action in the controller, the dictionary in parameter contains

```
[0][mail,gmail]
[1][name,Chris]
```