# How to override global ModelBinder for specific post action mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have applied a global `ModelBinder` for `int` arrays as below:

```
public class IntArrayModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                     ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {

            return value
                .AttemptedValue
                .Split(',')
                .Select(int.Parse)
                .ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then register this `IntArrayModelBinder` in `global.asax.cs` as below

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(int[]), new IntArrayModelBinder());
```

Now I want to ignore this model binder in a specific post action and use the default binding.

My `ViewModel` is

```
public class AddListViewModel
{
    public string[] SelectedNames { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedList { get; set; }
}
```

And my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddInList(AddListViewModel vm)
{
    //  code here
}
```

But the result of `SelectedList` is always null. Binding does not work. If I disable the global custom binding then the binding works fine.

I tried to specify the `DefaultModelBinder` as below, but no success

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddCompaniesInList(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(DefaultModelBinder))]AddListViewModel vm)
{}
```

I even created another custom default binder to add the action. But it still seems that default binder overrides my action binder and the result is always null.

How can I ignore default global binding for a specific action?

Comment: You can actually insert a ParameterBinding into the ParameterBindingRulesCollection of the HttpConfig, and then create a custom model binder for when the type is detected. It is real simple