# Is there any possibility to map array from url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can I convert this url:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/hoursRange=[0,12]
```

to `int[] HoursRange`?
I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2

I tried this code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api")]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]int[] HoursRange)
{
    // action
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Receive it as text, and then parse it into an array.  Pretty simple, really; all you have to do is strip off the brackets and do a split on the comma.

Comment: if you could change the url to `http://localhost:4200/api/hoursRange=0&hoursRange=12`, it could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** 
The default model binder expects this url:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/hoursRange=1&hoursRange=2&hoursRange=3
```

Only work for this type of method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api")]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]int[] HoursRange)
{
    // action
}
```

**Solution 2:** 
to do that but in different method but in `asp.net mvc`

Need to change method name like this

```
http://localhost:54119/api/MultipleData?ids=24041&ids=24117
```

in order to successfully bind to:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api")]
public ActionResult MultipleData(int[] ids)
{
    ...
}
```

**Solution 3:** 
**For another verified solution check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508310/6923146)**

**Solution 4:** 
indexer is also one way to do but not an efficient way

```
http://localhost:4200/api/hoursRange[0]=24041&hoursRange[1]=24117&hoursRange[2]=24117
```

**Informations**

Please check for more customization 
[customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the title **Collections** in [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

It shows several ways in which this can be achieved.

A couple of the ways shown in the Microsoft documentation are:

```
hoursRange=0&hoursRange=12
```

Using an indexer

```
hoursRange[0]=0&hoursRange[1]=12
```