# How to use multi-valued/array parameter(enum values) obtained from Request.Query in LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm still new to modern styles .NET development and Entity Framework. I'm trying to get a list of objects where one of the values falls in a list of other values, and I'm trying to use the LINQ query methods to do so.

```
string cb_orderstatus = Request.Query["OrderStatusSearch"].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb_orderstatus))
{
    string[] orderStatuses = cb_orderstatus.Split(",");
    query = query.Where(o => orderStatuses.Contains(o.Status.ToString()));
}
```

If the value of the cb_orderstatus is a string array containing 5, 10, and 15, I want the query to return objects where their Status equals any of these values. Currently it is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: What type is `o.Status`?

Comment: and what is `query`?

Comment: Also, what does it mean not working? Does it throw an exception, what kind of exception or what kind of result it returns?

Comment: Your code appears to be logically correct. My educated guess is that the result of `o.Status.ToString()` is not what you expect or if it is, there is a problem with the string comparison.

Comment: If `Request.Query["OrderStatusSearch"]` is an array then the result of `ToString` is not going to be a comma separated list of the values.  It's going to be the type of the array like `"System.Int32[]"` for a `int[]`

Comment: if you could provide us with code we can reproduce, that would be helpful

Comment: I was hired to edit existing code, so there is a lot of code that I am dealing with that I did not write. I'm doing my best to understand it.

o.Status is an OrderStatus enum. 

query is an IQueryable defined earlier in the code as:
```
var query = _db.Orders.AsNoTracking();
```

_db is a DbContext. 

The URL is being requested with Search?OrderStatus=0&OrderStatusSearch2=10 and I have a property on the model class that has [BindProperty] on it and is of type List<int> but it is not being populated with any data.

Comment: There were line breaks in the above reply but they're not being properly displayed. :( I'm new to posting on StackOverflow and I haven't had the easiest time learning it, especially since it keeps telling me that I am banned from posting because my questions "have not been well received by the community."

Answer (score 2):

It is an educated guess, but as you say that

> o.Status is an OrderStatus enum

then most probably you need to convert values from `cb_orderstatus` to actual `OrderStatus`es values and use `OrderStatus[].Contains` in the query

```
string cb_orderstatus = Request.Query["OrderStatusSearch"].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb_orderstatus))
{
    var orderStatuses = cb_orderstatus
        .Split(",")
        .Select(statusIntegerString => 
            (OrderStatus)int.Parse(statusIntegerString))
        .ToArray();
    query = query.Where(o => orderStatuses.Contains(o.Status));
}
```

Though I am not sure that you will get comma-separated values from `Request.Query["OrderStatusSearch"]`.

In any case, it would be orders of magnitude better to rely on standard parameter [binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508265/how-do-i-accept-an-array-as-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-action-parameter), so I'd recommend you to post another question that deals with

> I have a property on the model class that has [BindProperty] on it and is of type List but it is not being populated with any data.