# Trying to pass an array to ajax load function but my controller doesn't get the array properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, url, parameter-passing

That is the JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dish-filter-form').on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dishName = encodeURIComponent($('#dishName').val());
        var selectFoodType = encodeURIComponent($('#selectFoodType').val());
        var cities = ["New-York", "Tokyo", "Madrid"];
        var strCities= JSON.stringify(cities);
        console.log(strCities);
        $('.toLoad').load('/Dishes/Search?dishName=' + dishName + "&cities[]=" + strCities+ + "&selectFoodType=" + selectFoodType);
    });
});
```

This is the signature of my Search method in DishesController:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string dishName, string[] cities, string selectFoodType)
```

When debugging I see that dishName and selectFoodType have been read well but cities is always an empty array, although that my console shows me that the array: `strCities` is as I wish.

Comment: You're not passing `strCities`; you've got `...cities[]=" + cities + "&...` there.

Comment: I posted the old version, I'm sorry. still doesn't work with strCities

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, arrays must be passed as individual parameters. See [How do I accept an array as an ASP.NET MVC controller action parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508265/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$(function () {
  $('#dish-filter-form').on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dishName = encodeURIComponent($('#dishName').val());
    var selectFoodType = encodeURIComponent($('#selectFoodType').val());
    var cities = ["New-York", "Tokyo", "Madrid"];
    var strCities= JSON.stringify(cities);
    console.log(strCities);
    $('.toLoad').load('/Dishes/Search?dishName=' + dishName + "&cities=" + strCities + "&selectFoodType=" + selectFoodType);
  });
});
```

Since you convert the Array to a String, you should pass the String into your GET Request.