# What HTTP Verb Should I Use For Comparing Data

Tags: http, http-verbs

I have an endpoint that takes a list of email address (could be a very long list) and finds users with that email. What HTTP verb is best for this?

I am thinking `GET` as there is no backend mutation but is `GET` ideal for sending this kind of data to the server?

Comment: How are you sending the data? A GET method wouldn't have a body, but would accept query parameters. GET makes the most sense to me based on what the request does.

Comment: That is another problem. How do I send a list with `GET` in an ideal and scalable way

Comment: I think that's a matter of opinion from what I've seen. You could specify the query parameter be comma separated. Or send duplicate query parameters, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621477/using-duplicate-parameters-in-a-url the second answer specifically.

Answer (score 2):

As you are only searching based on free-text I would suggest using GET, it covers everything you need.
Your method is not creating/updating/deleting any data, simply collecting and passing it back.
This is exactly the purpose of the GET method.