# Passsing List to Controller in Java or Spring?

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, controller

I have the following method and I need to pass `List<UUID>` to this Controller method.

```
@GetMapping("/product/{productUuidList}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<List<ProductDTO>>> getProductList(
        @RequestParam List<UUID> productUuidList) {

        // code omitted
}
```

If I pass the list parameters by separating comma, it is ok. But, I want to pass these list parameters as Json array. When I try to pass uuid parameters in Postman as shown below, I get *"productUuidList parameter is missing"* error.

```
{ 
    "productUuidList": ["c849bcbb-c26c-4299-9ca4-dcde56830f5f", "398ec0f8-86c8-400a-93cb-caf47c1ac92d"]
}
```

So, how should I properly pass uuid array to this Controller method without changing `@GetMapping` to `@PostMapping` ?

Comment: Does anybody else never pass List to an endpoint in Java?

Comment: you can convert the productUuidList as Query param and send the list of ids. Refer suggestions at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621477/using-duplicate-parameters-in-a-url

Comment: Yes, for eg. to get data from service based on multiple selections at UI like checkbox.

Comment: You're conflating `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody`.

Comment: @MSDev Thanks for helps, but there is not any useful thing on that pages. Any solution for this situation above?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like this. Here you are sending a JSON object that looks like this java POJO :

```
public class MyUUIDWrapper{

    private List<UUID> productUuidList;
    // GETTERS/SETTERS  

}
```

So Spring is expecting to retrieve a MyUUIDWrapper object in the RequestBody

If you change your code like this it should work :

```
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<List<ProductDTO>>> getProductList(
    @RequestParam MyUUIDWrapper uuids) {
```

NB : If you have troubles deserializing UUIDs (I've never done it before), change List to List. Not the smartest or most beautiful solution, but you can still convert them later in your controller ;)