# how to send an array in url request

Tags: java, web-services, spring, url, spring-mvc

My requirement is as follows:

I want to give actor name, start date, end date and get all the films he acted in that period.

For that reason, my service request is like this.

```
  http://localhost:8080/MovieDB/GetJson?name=Actor&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505
```

Now, i want to improve it.
I want to give a start date, end date and more than one actor name and want to see all those actors movies in that period.

I am not sure how should my url look to support such thing.

I am writing a java based web service using spring.

Below code is to support one actor

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/GetJson", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public void getJson(@RequestParam("name") String ticker, @RequestParam("startDate") String startDate, @RequestParam("endDate") String endDate) {
   //code to get results from db for those params.
 }
```

One solution i am thinking is using a % symbol to seperate actor names. For example:

```
 http://localhost:8080/MovieDB/GetJson?name=Actor1%Actor2%Actor3&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505
```

Now, in the controller i will parse the name string with % and get back all actors names.

Is this a good way to do this or is there a standard approach?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is fine for 3 or 4 actors. But if you want to pass in 100 actors, maybe you can use POST and then pass a javascript object. The object can have name-value pairs for each actor. What do you think? Sorry for a sketchy reply

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Separate with commas:

```
http://localhost:8080/MovieDB/GetJson?name=Actor1,Actor2,Actor3&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505
```

or:

```
http://localhost:8080/MovieDB/GetJson?name=Actor1&name=Actor2&name=Actor3&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505
```

or:

```
http://localhost:8080/MovieDB/GetJson?name[0]=Actor1&name[1]=Actor2&name[2]=Actor3&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505
```

Either way, your method signature needs to be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetJson", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public void getJson(@RequestParam("name") String[] ticker, @RequestParam("startDate") String startDate, @RequestParam("endDate") String endDate) {
   //code to get results from db for those params.
 }
```

Comment: but in case if u having 1000 size of array then u can not write this all the thing separate na.. ??

Comment: Is there a "Spring documentation" link you could point to regarding those 3 different ways of writing the URLs?

Comment: approach one (separate with commas) is different from the other two. Tried on a Java app (server side backed by undertow), if you pass `name=Actor1,Actor2,Actor3`, the server will not get an array for your `name` parameter, instead you get one single string: `Actor1,Actor2,Actor3` param. The other two is different, they all give `name` parameter with an array of values: `["Actor1", "Actor2", "Actor3"]`. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string, many other frameworks also treat approach one as a single string query param instead of array

Comment: with comma separated values you can receive them as a List<String> request param

Comment: For some reason, in Quarkus 2.10+, I sometimes can't map query parameters to a List<String> using the short form. If I repeated the field name I could map the query parameters to a List every time, but only switching to a String[] allowed for the short comma separated format to work consistently. Leaving this here in case it helps someone.

Comment: Brackets [] seems to be forbidden in the form of option 3 in IPv4 URI address.