# passing array to url node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an API http://studentresults.com/studentresults?studentname=xyz&date=dd/mm/yyyy

With the above url, I get `JSON` information w.r.t to student name on that date of examination.
I can get the `JSON` information for single student by parsing url using node js.
Now I have 15 students. How to get to all the information on that particular day of examination so that I create object such as

```
          {
               "date": dd/mm/yyyy
                 'studentresults': [
                  { 'studentname' = xyz , marks = 500 },
                  { 'studentname' = abc , marks = 525 },
                   so on
                  ]
           }
```

In the above url, by changing the student name we get information of one student details. if i need to get all the students details how it can be done ? instead of changing every time how can i pass a array of studentnames to url so that i can all the information at once ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What do you exactly need?

Comment: Are you wanting to include a list of names and date in your query string?

Comment: I know it sounds awful, and actually looks awful, but you can use encodeURIComponents to get the json into your url directly

Comment: Is it your own API ? If you're not maintening this API, you can't pass en array if the doc don't allow you to do that.

Comment: @Josh C - do you want me to use in this way : querystringfy({studentname: ['xyz', 'abc' ... ]});

Comment: @KevinLabécot- it's not my own api, how can i check if it does parse array or not(can you post any example of passing array to url)

Comment: No I can't. Check your API's doc. If there is no info about passing an array, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can edit the api:

If you get url with "studentname" (one) and "date" get the desired student data.

**url.com/studentresults?studentname=xyz&date=dd/mm/yyyy**

Else if you get url with multiple studentnames then you need to check if "studentname" is an array.

**url.com/studentresults?studentname=student1,student2&date=dd/mm/yyyy**

[More details how to pass array to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889997/how-to-send-a-array-in-url-request)

Else if you get only date then try getting all the results of the day.

**url.com/studentresults?date=dd/mm/yyyy**

If you can't edit then you must check the API for allowed parameters which can be passed.

Comment: You can't recommend him to test on the fly. He's using an API, he must send data in an expected format that we can't know. He must read the doc of this API.

Comment: Your right. I assumed it's his own API, that he can modify, because he mentioned Node.js in the title.

Comment: yes... that was my question too. He answered above, it's not his API.

Comment: My bad, i am blind, didn't see "2 more comments" button.