# Yii2 - GridView - How Sorting works?

Tags: php, html, gridview, yii2

I am trying to understand how sorting works in `GridView` by means of generating a default `CRUD` application. Sorting happens after clicking the respective attribute which is the table header. The column name is attached to the url with the variable **sort** and on click the action method is invoked, but what I am wondering is that the action method which is mentioned in the url with the actual variable `$sort` is not present in the controller.

Below is a example

The url looks like the below,

> /advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex&***sort=customer_user_name2***

But there is no corresponding action method in the site controller as
function `actionIndex($sort)`;

Answer (score 0):

Consider following example

We have Passenger CRUD

Consider Passenger - a model and PassengerSearch - its corresponding search model

Passenger attribute are id, name and country_name

In `PassengerController.php`

```
<?php
...
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new PassengerSearch();    
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
...
?>
```

Search string `a` in name column
and sort id column in `desc` order

Look at the url generated, it would be like

```
`http://localhost/YII2proj/passenger/index?PassengerSearch%5Bid%5D=&PassengerSearch%5Bname%5D=a&PassengerSearch%5Bcountry_name%5D=&sort=-id`
```

In human readable format

```
http://localhost/YII2proj/passenger/index?
PassengerSearch[id]=&
PassengerSearch[name]=a&
PassengerSearch[country_name]=&
sort=-id
```

Observe `PassengerSearch` is a array. Please refer - [How to send a array in url request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889997/how-to-send-a-array-in-url-request)

Focus on the parameter to `search()` method of object `PassengerSearch` class it is `Yii::$app->request->queryParams`

Before 
    `$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);`

line, insert following code

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

and see the result

```
Array
(
    [PassengerSearch] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => a
            [country_name] => 
        )

    [sort] => -id
)
```

If no searching sorting done, then this array will be empty

So this line does your code like following

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sort']) ||  isset($_GET['PassengerSearch']['id'] ...)
{
    // validate it because what if I changed url like
    // `http://localhost/YII2proj/passenger/index?PassengerSearcasdh[dfsid]=&PassengerSearch[name]=a&PassengerSearch[country_name]=&sorsfdft=-idadlashdfhls`
    // ie some scrap value
    // If error returned from validate function, default sorting is done, and malformed search param is not set
    // if success, fill up that array
}
?>
```

Then in search Model `load()` is the hero.

Where and how above code is done? - [Refer Model and `load()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail)

Searching is done via [`andFilterWhere`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) after loading ie `load()` and  that you can see in `search()` method

Hope you got the idea behind searching and sorting.