# Java serialization of a query to list of strings

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I stumbled upon a strange issue and cant find quick solution to deal with it. Front side of my application sends query to back-end I added square brackets for readability.

as it should be
http://localhost:3000/?params=[First_value],[Anhui Jantene Hone Textiles Co., Ltd.],[Third_Value]

as it is
http://localhost:3000/?params=[first_value],**[Anhui Jantene Hone Textiles Co.], [Ltd.]**,[Third_Value]

params are serialized to List but there is a problem when given value on a front-side has comma in the name, then instead of one value I get 2 entries. In a given example expected size of a list should be 3 but I get 4 elements.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the query string because of how a comma is treated. You need to use a POST with a request body like this:

```
["First_value", "Anhui Jantene Hone Textiles Co., Ltd.","Third_Value"]
```

Comment: Apparently, there is a way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889997/how-to-send-an-array-in-url-request