# Read Array From Query String?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, query-string

Can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.

I'm using [Alex K.'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) to send the array in the query string, but I don't know how to break down the array in VB.NET.

No variation of this

```
 Dim qryArray As String() = context.Request.QueryString("qryArray")
```

is working.  It keeps saying qryArray is not declared when I try to use it.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I used this format to send the values in the query string:

```
qryArray =[value1,...,valueN]
```

Thanks again for taking your time to help!

Comment: AlexK gave three different answers at that link.  You will need to be clear about how your query string is coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try like below example I used..It is created using arraylist. result will be a string in form of ("value10,value11,value12,value13") which is ready to be passed in query.In first array i.e array1, remove the duplicates

```
    Dim Array1 As New ArrayList
    Dim Array_Com As New ArrayList
    Dim Word_1 As String = "Value1"
    Dim word_2 As String = "("""
    Dim i As Int32
    Dim j As Int32
    Dim k As Int32 = Array1.Count

    For i = 0 To 3
        Array1.Add(Word_1 & i)
    Next
    For j = 0 To Array1.Count - 1
        If k < Array1.Count - 1 Then
            Array_Com.Add(Array1.Item(j) & ",")
            'MsgBox(Array_Com.Item(j))
            k += 1
        Else
            Array_Com.Add(Array1.Item(j) & """" & ")")
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Haroon - you can just delete your answer if you're not happy with it.