# passing array via query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am passing a javascript array via `Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString()`, but it shows me an error of  "invalid arguments":

```
blObj.addOfficeOnlyDiffrent(Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString(),
                            Request.QueryString["selectTxtOfficeAr"].ToString());
```

The method declaration looks like:

```
public string addOfficeOnlyDiffrent(string[] cityID, string selectTxtOfficeAr) { }
```

Comment: how your query string looks like?

Comment: You may find your answer in this thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString()
(123456,654311,987654)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method `addOfficeOnlyDiffrent` is expecting a string array arguement in `cityID` whereas you are passing a single `string` type object to your method in call. I believe your `cityID` is a single string so you can remove the array from the method declaration. In your method call.

```
Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString()
```

the above represents a single string, not a string array.

If your query string contains a string array, then values are probably in string representation, separated by some character, for example `,`. To pass that string to the method, you can call `string.Split` to split the string to get an array.

EDIT:
From your comment, that your query string contains:

```
Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString() (123456,654311,987654)
```

You can do the following.

```
string str = Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString();
string[] array = str.Trim('(',')').Split(',');
blObj.addOfficeOnlyDiffrent(array,
                            Request.QueryString["selectTxtOfficeAr"].ToString());
```

Comment: Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString() havaing multiple iD whic i need to pass addOfficeOnlyDiffrent metod
HOW CAN I DO THAT

Comment: @SHAKEELHUSSAIN, how does your query string looks like ?

Comment: Request.QueryString["cityID"].ToString() (123456,654311,987654)

Answer (score 2):

If your query string parameter value looks like: "123456,654311,987654"

```
string[] ids = Request.QueryString["cityID"]
    .Split( new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it's so **simple**.

```
 string city = Request.QueryString["cityID"];

 string[] cityID =city.Split(new char[] {','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You get string like this "123456,654311,987654" in **city**. You get array in cityID.