# can vb.net read query strings with field[] format?

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, query-string, httphandler

I'm trying to navigate through not being able to read multidimensional arrays with `JavaScriptSerializer`.

I think there's a workaround if I can do what's in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/1382306

Basically, if I can store json arrays in each `field[]` and loop through `field`, it should be no problem.

How do I loop through `field` if it's in the query string of this format

```
?field[]=["a","b","c"]&field[]=["d","e","f"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Request.QueryString ["field[]"][0]
```

... to return:

```
["a","b","c"]        {in quotes}
```

and

```
Request.QueryString ["field[]"][1]
```

... to return:

```
["d","e","f"]
```

You will have to strip off the square brackets and then use split () over the commas.

Comment: `HttpContext.Request.QueryString("field[]")` grabs both of them as a character array