# ZF2, Passing arrays as query parameters, esp in Zend\Http\Request

Tags: php, zend-framework2

### Question:

Anyone know of a way to cajole the Zend\Http\Request (or perhaps it would be in an implementer of Zend\Stdlib\ParametersInterface?) into creating urls where array query arg keys don't contain the indexes.

### Background:

I'm attempting to pass an array of values as a query parameter on a GET request using the Zend\Http\Request object.

```
...
$httpClient = new Zend\Http\Client(); // cURL adapter setup omitted
$request = new Zend\Http\Request();  // set url, set GET method omitted

$myQueryArgArray = [ 
    'key0' => 'val0',
    'key1' => ['val1', 'val2'],
];
$request->getQuery()->fromArray($myQueryArgArray);

$response = $httpClient->send($request);
...
```

The cURL adapter is sending the request out the door with a url that looks like this:

```
hostname/path?key0=val0&key1%5B0%5D=val1&key1%5B1%5D=val2
```

Without the encoding:

```
hostname/path/?key0=val0&key1[0]=val1&key1[1]=val2
```

However, the server I'm calling out to fails unless I do *NOT* pass indexes in the query string. That is, before URL-encoding, I can call my API endpoint with a url like:

```
hostname/path?key0=val0&key1[]=val1&key1[]=val2
```

### The question (again :):

Anyone know of a way to cajole the Zend\Http\Request (or perhaps it would be in an implementer of Zend\Stdlib\ParametersInterface?) into creating urls where array query arg keys don't contain the indexes.

### What I've tried:

I've tried wrapping my array in a Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject:

```
...
$myQueryArgArray = [ 
    'key0' => 'val0',
    'key1' => new \Zend\StdLib\ArrayObject(['val1', 'val2']),
];
...
```

Alas, to no avail.

I know that I accomplish the goal by manually constructing my query string and handing it directly to the Zend\Http\Request object, but I'm looking for a better way than creating my own query strings.

This page seems to indicate that there isn't a standard, so I suppose that neither ZF2 nor my api endpoint are doing it wrong:
[How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked at the sources and the problem is not the [Zend\Http\Request](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Request.php) class but the [Zend\Http\Client](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Client.php).

Look at [line 843](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Client.php#L843) you see a call to the [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function. And on the php.net site you have a solution in the comments:

```
$query = http_build_query($query);
$query = preg_replace('/%5B[0-9]+%5D/simU', '%5B%5D', $query);
```

So the cleanest solution probably would be to extend the `Zend\Http\Client` class and override the `send` method.

Comment: Bleh, that's a tiny little change to a huge method, but I don't see any better entry points. Looks good, thanks!