# What if query string itself contains comma when using comma-separated query string API?

Tags: php, api

I'm designing an API, but here is a problem:

```
?merchantCategoryName=[Adult,Fantasy,Mac]
&mappedCategoryID=[701,80,22]
&merchantID=36330&outputType=xml
```

This is ideal situation, but what if `merchantCategoryName` contains a comma like this: (`Ad,ult` is a `merchantCategoryName`)

```
?merchantCategoryName=[Ad,ult,Fantasy,Mac]
&mappedCategoryID=[701,80,22]
&merchantID=36330&outputType=xml
```

Then will be disorder, if I use `base64` it seems not work, if I use `htmlentities` it seems `,`'s entity is `,`. so how can I solve this?

Comment: use a different delimiter perhaps

Comment: @RamRaider I think every delimiter has opportunity to have this situation, especially my project is multi-language support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format:

```
?merchantCategoryName[]=Adult&
merchantCategoryName[]=Fantasy&
merchantCategoryName[]=Mac&
merchantID=36330&
outputType=xml
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) question for details

Comment: But my receive point is JAVA, JAVA will parse this URL, is it work in JAVA?

Comment: And also, there is a chance that `merchantCategoryName` can be `Adu&lt`

Comment: I don't know about JAVA, you set tag `php` :) For escaping special characters in php you need to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: Yes it's PHP parse the url, JAVA is API provider

Comment: If I use `urlencode`, all commas will be encoded including the sepatator

Comment: You need to encode only data, not query string. For example:

`foreach ($categories as $category) { $queryString .= "merchantCategoryName[]=" . urlencode($category) . "&" }`