# Postman: How to pass an array within an http header

Tags: arrays, header, postman

So far I tried: (In Bulk Edit)

myHeader:myValue1,myValue2,myValue3

myHeader:[myValue1,myValue2,myValue3]

myHeader:{myValue1,myValue2,myValue3}

Unfortunately I cannot say if one of these should work as I'm using a foreign API and I don't know if I'm maybe doing wrong something different which lets the request fail.

This answer [How to pass an array within a http header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139035/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-http-header) seems wrong to me as the answer suggests to put the header in the params...

Answer (score 0):

You can add key value parameters from the postman desktop app. You can add the content-type, auth token and things like that. Here is an example. Good Luck!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but for others:
[image]

Try to add your header multiple times