# Wordpress post listing, duplicate parameters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is a WordPress URL with parameters `post_type` and `post_status`.

```
https://www.example.co.uk/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order&post_status=wc-pending
```

I need two `post_status` so the query fetches both, which would be an `OR` condition in the query but this would require editing the core.

`https://www.example.co.uk/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order&post_status=wc-pending&post_status=wc-processing`

This only fetches `wc-processing`, when i want it two fetch both `wc-processing` and `wc-pending`.

Is there anyway to do this so that I don't have to edit the core files of WordPress?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an array within a query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Answer (score 1):

The [post status parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters) accept an array:

```
https://www.example.co.uk/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order&post_status[]=wc-pending&post_status[]=wc-processing
```

Comment: i tried this `edit.php?post_type=shop_order&post_status[]=wc-completed&post_status[]=wc-processing` and results with `wc-pending` are returning.  Any idea why?