# How to get specific data when pass multiple parameter at the end of url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.2 of my application.

Below is index action of my Descriptions Controller.

```
def index
  @descriptions = Description.all
  if name = params[:name]
    description = @descriptions.where(name: name)
    render json: description
  end
end
```

and when I input http://localhost:3000/descriptions?name=LA to browser.
I can get a data which name attributes is "LA" in JSON format.
like below.

```
[{"id":140,"name":"LA","value":"Lakers","api_name_id":113,"created_at":"2015-06-04T17:11:18.649Z","updated_at":"2015-06-04T17:11:18.649Z"}]
```

However, if I pass two parameter at the end of my url like

```
http://localhost:3000/descriptions?name=LA&name=123
```

I can only get data which name attributes is "123" in JSON format.

```
[{"id":143,"name":"123","value":"456","api_name_id":114,"created_at":"2015-06-04T17:20:18.703Z","updated_at":"2015-06-04T17:20:18.703Z"}]
```

Is there any way that I can get all datas which name attributes is "LA" and also "123" ? Like below

```
[{"id":143,"name":"123","value":"456","api_name_id":114,"created_at":"2015-06-04T17:20:18.703Z","updated_at":"2015-06-04T17:20:18.703Z"},{"id":140,"name":"LA","value":"Lakers","api_name_id":113,"created_at":"2015-06-04T17:11:18.649Z","updated_at":"2015-06-04T17:11:18.649Z"}]
```

Comment: How and is possible ?

Comment: What is mean is all datas which name=LA or name=123. (this and is not &&) XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the url as :

```
http://localhost:3000/descriptions?name[]=LA&name[]=123
```

And rest your code is perfect. But remember `where` will do SQL `IN` operation. Look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/4962117) to see how to pass array like elements with *query string*.

Comment: what if i pass two different attribute? one is "name" and another one is "value"..like  http://localhost:3000/descriptions?name=LA&value=456

Comment: @LateBloomer That depends on how you  want the query... AND or OR?

Comment: if OR??How to implement?

Comment: @LateBloomer `@descriptions.where("name = ? OR value = ?", params[:name], params[:value])`

Comment: I really apreciate.Is there any way that can pass two same attribute?like localhost:3000/descriptions?name=LA&name=NY&value=456&value=789

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79693/discussion-between-r-o-r-and-latebloomer).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you'll want

```
unless params.empty?
 description = {}
 params.each do |key, value|
  description.merge(@descriptions.where(name: value)) if key == name
 end
end
```