# rails multiple params(:filter) request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

When i use select with multiple options, form send such get request:

```
/saveProduct?tags=1&tags=2
```

so I need to get them with params[:tags], but it takes only last string. How to get all of them?

EDIT:

```
<%= form_tag("/saveProduct", multipart: true, method: :get) do %>
 <select multiple="multiple" class="tagsSelect" name = "tags" >
    <option value = 1 >123</option>
     <option value = 2 >dfsd</option>
</select>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Show your HTML where you have fields 'tags'. Above is the wrong query string

Comment: @Raj I add it, can you checkout plz

Comment: @Зелёный can you add it as answer? It works! Thank you!

Comment: @old_school mark below answer as accepted. Happy coding!

Comment: @Зеленый I know ;) there are some time limits in SF, so after few minutes I will be able to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `select`'s `name` attribute should be `tags[]` to support multiple values.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="tagsSelect" name = "tags[]" >
```

Now when you will do `params[:tags]` you will get an array of values in your action.

[`How to pass an array within a query string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)