# $http.get doesn't work with arrays with only one element. How do I specify the param type?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http

I'm using Angular's [`$http.get()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) method to query my API:

```
var arr = ['foo','bar'];
return $http.get("api/foo", {
  params: { sampleids: arr}
});
```

This results in a request to `/api/foo?sampleids=115&sampleids=116` which works ok. If I reduce the size of the array to a single element, however, it becomes `/api/foo?sampleids=115`, which [express (node.js) fails to interpret as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string#comment30036936_9547490).

If Angular sent the query as `/api/foo?sampleids[]=115` instead, it should work fine. Is there any way I can tell it to do that?

Comment: IMHO I would never send an array over the HTTP Get params..... Just easier to post them

Comment: Hm, that's very interesting. There's no way I know of, aside from producing a little function to manually create such urls.

Comment: Look into using the alternate param serializer -- [AngularJS $httpParamSerializerJQLike Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike). It is more versatile than `$httpParamSerializer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `paramSerializer` property in your request config to customize how the parameters object gets converted to a string.

```
return $http.get("api/foo", {
  params: { myArray: arr},
  paramSerializer: function (params) {
      // Return a string...
  }
});
```

You can look at the default implementation here, if you're not sure how to go about serializing the object: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L27.

Additionally, if you provide a string rather than a function, it will look for a service with that name - this could be helpful if you want to reuse it. There's a `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` service provided by default, which serializes them in the same format as jQuery's `param()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some uncertainty how to best implement arrays as parameters. 
You could try using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var arr = ['foo','bar'];
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api/foo',
  params: {
    arr: JSON.stringify(arr) 
})
```

Or simply:

```
var arr = ['foo','bar'];
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api/foo',
  params: {
    "arr[]": arr
})
```

You might find this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) useful

Comment: I linked to that very SO article in my question :) And your simplification becomes `?arr%5B%5D=226&arr%5B%5D=227` (though express doesn't seem to mind)