# Designing REST URL for resource with multiple identifiers

Tags: web-services, rest

If `PUT` and `DELETE` operations can be performed on a *profile* resource by passing either `profileId` or `profileName` (both are unique), what is the right way to form URLs?

I want to support both *update* and *delete* operations on a profile resource when sending the `profileId` and support both *update* and *delete* operations on a profile resource when sending the `profileName`.

When sending the `profileId`, the URL for performing `PUT` operations would look like:

```
/api/profiles/{profileId}
```

How would the URL look like when sending the `profileName`? Should the `profileName` be sent as a query parameter?

```
/api/profiles?profileName=uniqueProfileName
```

Or is there any better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: this will help you here you will find how to send an array in url, with this array you can treat the ids that you want to delete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: We want to support both : That's Update/Delete a profile by profileId and Update/Delete a profile by profileName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `profileId` as a *main identifier* for your profile resources:

```
/api/profiles/{profileId}
```

And you could support the `{profileName}` as a *secondary identifier* by using a query parameter:

```
/api/profiles?name={profileName}
```

Or a matrix parameter:

```
/api/profiles;name={profileName}
```

Comment: I've designed the `ProfileResource` to support both main identifier and secondary identifier (profileId and profileName). Getting an error. Question has been updated. Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: @VGHegde It looks out of the scope of the original question. Why don't you ask a new question. I'll be happy to help you there. *Tip:* you could use the query string in the method that returns all profiles and avoid ambiguity.

Comment: New question : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298844/designing-rest-resource-to-support-multiple-methods-which-produces-and-consumes)