# Designing REST resource to support multiple methods which produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I have 3 methods in `ProfileResource`:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Profile> getAllProfiles() {
    return profileService.getAllProfiles();
}

@GET
@Path("{profileId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Profile getProfile(@PathParam("profileId") String profileId) {
    return profileService.getProfile(profileId);
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Profile getProfileByName(@QueryParam("profileName") String profileName) {
    return profileService.getProfileByName(profileName);
}
```

During server startup below error is thrown, since both `getAllProfiles` and `getProfileByName` methods are `GET` methods, both produce `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` and there is no `Path` difference b/n them.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public restapi.model.Profile restapi.resources.ProfileResource.getProfileByName(java.lang.String) and public java.util.List restapi.resources.ProfileResource.getAllProfiles() at matching regular expression /profiles. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@4e1d247f']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555) ~[jersey-server-2.22.2.jar:na]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have differentiate Both getAllProfiles() and  getProfileByName() by providing difference paths to access them, unless that the server can not distinguish them. so that you will get below error.

> A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET

provide different paths for both of them, you can do that using @path() annotation.

Comment: Can't we solve this issue without providing a new Path ?

Comment: thats what i said in the answer

Comment: @Tom Howard Any inputs ?