# Why does Angular 2 converts the URL to have only query param of that name?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a URL which is a different application on which I don't have a control. I am making a get call from that Form of diff application to my site. It works well and I get the params in url.
The other application is a different hosted application.
The code is:

```
// localhost will be replaced by our new application url
<form action="shoppingcart.php" method="post">

will be changed to:


<form action="http://localhost:3000/add" method="get">

<input title="product_ids" name="product_ids" value="1001930" type="checkbox">
<input title="product_ids" name="product_ids" value="1001921" type="checkbox">
<input title="product_ids" name="product_ids" value="1001912" type="checkbox">

<input type="submit" value="Add Product"/>
</form>
```

But it converts the url. The URL is

```
localhost:3000/add?product_id=1&product_id=2&product_id=3
```

Here all the field of query params are same. Whenever I load this url it automatically converts url to

```
localhost:3000/add?product_id=3
```

and then processes my file which has ActivatedRoute.queryParam to get those query param. I am not sure why it changes the url automatically and gives the id of last one everytime.

Comment: Can you please try if `localhost:3000/add?product_id[]=1&product_id[]=2&product_id[]=3` also gets converted?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a standard way to handle multiple values for the same query param.

Comment: Yes it converts the url even if I append [ ].

Comment: I can even parse the url with router.url.split("&") and doing some dirty work I can get the product_ids. But it doesn't even let it remain as it is. Just converts it.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Posting the code that shows how you make the request and how you pass the params to the request might help

Comment: Your code doesn't look like angular is involved at all. This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: Angular doesn't need any involvement until I go to that url and parse it.