# How to create ajersey restful method that can accept three arrays of strings

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jersey

I have been trying to send string arrays to a restful services without any luck. I have written this

```
@GET   
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getBackgroundImages(@QueryParam("missions") String[] missions, 
                                  @QueryParam("objects")String[] objects, 
                                  @QueryParam("dates")String[] dates) {

 ........       


  return generateTxt();
```

}

on the javascript side I have this

```
   var missions = new Array("One", "Two");
          var objects = new Array("objOne" ,"objTwo");
          var dates = new Array("1967-11-07","1977-12-17");                        
         $.ajax({
            url: "myurl/rest/UploadBackgroundFile/",
            data: {'missions':missions,'objects':objects,'dates':dates},

            success: function (data) {                    
                 arr = JSON.parse(data);
                $('.container-fluid').css('background-image','url('+arr[0].img+')');    
            }
        });
```

my problem is that this is not working and I am getting this exception

> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
>   [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type 
>   public java.lang.String UploadBackgroundFile.getBackgroundImages(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])

if I change the parameters to normal string and send strings from the javascript side than the method will work.

so the question is how to send and receive string arrays from the jquery ajax to the jersey restful method.

with regards,

es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side, you have to change the string array to a `List<String>` to make it work.

Client side, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)  to help you how to send the datas. I know in title it's write PHP, but it's well explained.