# Laravel pagination: Append query parameter without value

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.4

I have a pagination-instance where I want to append all query parameter from the request to the `next_page_url` attribute.

I have query parameter with a value like `&name=chris` but I also have single parameter without a value like `&xyz`.

However, when I append all query parameters to the pagination instance, like so:

```
$query->simplePaginate(50)->appends($request->all());
```

only parameters with a value are getting appended.

How can I append all parameters to the `next_page_url`?

#### Update

I want to append query parameters to get the next chunk of requested data.

If I don't, it always gives back "next_page_url":"http://vue.dev/contacts?page=2". What I want is "next_page_url":"http://vue.dev/contacts?name&page=2"

Comment: Was wondering, why do you want to append a query parameter?

Comment: @joshuamabina to get the next chunk of requested data. If I don't append it always gives back "next_page_url":"http:\/\/vue.dev\/contacts?page=2". What I want is "next_page_url":"http:\/\/vue.dev\/contacts?name&page=2"

Comment: With what use do you have with the extra arguments (i.e. name)? The `next_page_url` is just supposed to hold the **url of the next page**.

Comment: Try this : `$query->simplePaginate(50)->appends(Input::query());`

Comment: @SKJajoriya same result.

Comment: @joshuamabina the parameter without value are the columns that get selected from the query

Comment: You can make it `&select=xyz` if needed since the `appends` always adds it as a key value pair.

Comment: As @joshuamabina have said, why do you need `name` in the URL? Will that actually toggle something on/off?

Comment: @Fahmi yes it will change the 'appearance' of the data

Comment: @ayip I could do that, just thought there would be a way without the overhead...

Comment: Alright then just do as @ayip suggested. `&name` alone doesn't quite "follow" REST convention since it doesn't fully describe what you mean by that. By doing for example `&select=name,age,gender`, it clearly shows its purpose.

Comment: @Fahmi did it that way with `&select[]=xyz&select[]=abc`. Just answer the question that I can accept for future reference.

Comment: Added my answer. I wouldn't suggest you to use `&select[]=xyz&select[]=abc` since we can achieve the same result with a cleaner looking URL. Have a look at my answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Fahmis solution is possible as well, I end up using the approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) so-question. This has the advantage that php reads the parameter as an array automatically. My url end up looking like this:

```
http://vue.dev/contacts?page=2&select[]=xyz&select[]=abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Take URL `http://vue.dev/contacts?page=2&name` for example. Although perfectly valid, it's still quite ambiguous. Do we mean to *include* name? Do we mean to  *exclude* name?

So I'd suggest you to use this URL instead `http://vue.dev/contacts?page=2&select=name`. If you decide to select more stuff you can just do `http://vue.dev/contacts?page=2&select=name,age,gender`.

Later in your code just use `explode` to use the value as an array:

```
$attributes = explode(',', $request->select);
```

Useful reading: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api