# Its possible send array in url

Tags: java, android, arrays, url

I would like to know if i can send an array of this type `endate []` in the parameter fecha2 of the following url:

http://www.xxxx.com/app/disponibilidad?idUser&fecha2&fecha1&desde&hasta

`endate[]` has several date I want to send in a single url. I would like to know if that is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a good idea in [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

You can also encode it to JSON and pass it as a single string, then decode it on your backend. Sounds simpler to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how to address the json encoding to the server www.xxxx.com/app/ disponibilidad

Comment: You can create a JSON string from an array with Javascript's function`JSON.stringify(arr);`

Comment: If you're thinking in pass a json as a query parameter, I think you may use a post instead of a get

Comment: But as concatenary this url: http://www.xxxx.com/app/prueba url.  With this json: {"disponibilidad":[{"idUser":"4","fecha2":"30 June, 2017","fecha1":"28 June, 2017","slotH":"1 hora","desde":"11:00 AM","hasta":"03:00 PM","entre":"10 minutos"},{"idUser":"4","fecha2":"30 June, 2017","fecha1":"29 June, 2017","slotH":"30 minutos","desde":"04:00 PM","hasta":"06:00 PM","entre":"15 minutos"}]}

Comment: if you wish to pass all that as GET parameters, then concatenate it as
`"xxxx.com/app/disponibilidad?Myarray="+JSON.stringify(arr)`