# Convert string to array in API call

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am passing an array as a string in parameter to an api in php like this:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api.php?query="array(done = 1)"
```

In my api file, I have used this array to hit a mongodb query:

```
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

But this didn't work. When I hard-coded `array(done = 1)` into the `find` query, it seems to work fine.

```
if (array('done' => 1) == $query) {
  echo "Y";
}
else {
  echo "N";
}
```

The above code prints `N`. So I guess it's because `$query` is being passed as a string.

PS: I also tried json_encode, json_decode and unserialize but it didn't work. I might be doing omething wrong here.

Comment: How did you try with json_encode ? Show us please...

Comment: Use `serialize()` and `unserialize()` or do it with sessions.

Comment: You can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Answer (score 1):

Well make bit change in your query string, you passing in api request.

Suppose belowis your array.

```
$array = array('done' => 1, 'message' => 'success');
```

USE `array_map_assoc` function with some customization, which make easy to implode associative array

```
function array_map_assoc( $callback , $array ){
  $r = array();
  foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
    $r[$key] = $callback($key,$value);
  return $r;
}
```

Generate your data to be sent in api
our data

```
$queryString = implode('&',array_map_assoc(function($k,$v){return "$k=$v";},$array));
```

Now send your data with API

```
$url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api.php?" . $queryString ;
```

Now use `print_r($_GET)` in your API page and you will receive data like below

```
Array
(
    [done] => 1
    [message] => success
)
```

This make your code easy to handle and use in either if condition or sql query.