# How to pass array values to a url from php

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, url

i have some thing like this in my html multi checkbox

```html
<label for="Status"><h2>Status:</h2></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="new">New<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="assigned">Assigned<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="resolved">Resolved<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="verified">Verified<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="closed">Closed<br>
```

myphp

```
$status = $_POST["status"];

$url = "http://some-example.com/project="abc" and state in [".$status."]/";
header("Location:$url");
```

i want the url to be like:

```
$url = "http://some-example.com/project="abc" and state in ["new","assigned","resolved","verified","closed"]/
```

is it possible to do this? if so please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Answer (score 2):

Use `http_build_query`   :

```
$url = "http://some-example.com/" . http_build_query([
    "project" => "abc",
    "state" => ["new","assigned","resolved","verified","closed"]
]);
```

Output :

```
http://some-example.com/project=abc&state%5B0%5D=new&state%5B1%5D=assigned&state%5B2%5D=resolved&state%5B3%5D=verified&state%5B4%5D=closed
```