# standard for representing arrays of integers in a url request

Tags: javascript, http

Is there a standard for handling an array of integers like the following:

```
http://localhost:3001/?tag_ids=7,10,45
```

or

```
http://localhost:3001/?tag_ids=[7,10,45]
```

I feel like I've written boiler-plate every 6 months and would much rather use some library.

Comment: Probably JSON is the simplest thing.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: hmm...... yeah, might be the way to go.  like: `encodeURI(["blue","some"]);` gives me `"blue","some"`. yeah, that makes sense - the boilerplate is fine and I pretty much always do this as integers

Answer (score 0):

A number of server-side scripting languages like PHP expect each value to be in a separate parameter, with the parameter name ending with `[]`.

```
tag_ids[]=7&tag_ids[]=10&tag_ids[]=45
```

They recognize this syntax and collect all the values into an array. In PHP this would be `$_GET['tag_ids'] = [7, 10, 45]`.

You can also optionally put strings inside the `[]`; in this case, the server language will put them into its keyed data structure (associative array in PHP, dictionary in Python) with those as the keys.

You should call `encodeURIComponent` on `tag_ids[]`, so they'll actually end up looking like `tag_ids%5B%5D`.