# Laravel - How to pass variable to WhereIn

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

New to Laravel. I am trying to use a controller to services that match what is sent in the URL.

Sample URL:

```
/public/service/cost/2
```

The Code in the Controller is:

```
public function getServiceCost($id) {

    $service = Service::whereIn('id', array($id))->get();

    return $service;
}
```

I want to be able to pass multiple ids in the URL like so:
/public/service/cost/1,2,3

If I hard-code to test, it works fine.

```
public function getServiceCost($id) {
  $service = Service::whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
  return $service;
}
```

What do I need to do to pass the arguments from the URL into the whereIn so that it returns what I pass in the URL?

If I use

```
/public/service/cost/2,3
```

It only returns the data for id 2.

I changed the function to use Request $request, but it still only shows one result:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Service;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{ 
    public function getServiceCost2(Request $request) {
        $service = Service::whereIn('id', array($request->get('id')))->get();

        return $service;
    }
}
```

URL used was:

```
public/service/cost?id=1,2
```

Comment: I suggest you check how to pass an array via query string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Answer (score 1):

Hi @BillyB you need to rethink your **URL Structure**, you can pass multiple parameters using GET Parameters.

I would recommend you to create service URL:

```
/public/service/cost?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

The Code in the Controller is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

.....

public function getServiceCost(Request $request) {

    $service = Service::whereIn('id',$request->get('id'))->get();

    return $service;
}
```

Its well documented at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

Comment: /public/service/cost?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3 didn't work either.  Is my route in web.php correct with Route::get('/service/cost/','ServiceController@getServiceCost2');

Comment: Yes it look good. just visit /service/cost?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3 otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Still not working.  Trying to teach myself Laravel so there could be something I missed.  Can I link the git repository?

Comment: Yes I can have look.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change your **route method** passing to **POST**, and your form will make a **name** like this, for example:

`<input type="text" name="id[]" />`

And doing this way, you can catch in your controller an array with multiple **ids**, using:

```
request()->get('id');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try use:

```
$arr = explode(',',$id)
```

They u will  have a array with ids