# Pass array in JavaScript to another page without using sessionStorage or localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does anyone know how to pass an `array` value to another page without using `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`?

Comment: cookie??????????????????

Comment: An "array" is very different from an "array value".

Comment: Is this two pages that load one after the other? Or two pages in two tabs open at the same time? Or a main page and a popup window? Please be as specific as you can.

Comment: stringy it and pass it through the query-string

Comment: @PeterB the page is call one after another. For example, i click a button to redirect to another page. Then the array value i declare will pass the another page(to perform edit or delete the value inside the array)

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: @SunnySoni yes, javascript or jquery i have used

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you have a page; you want to send some data to another page, by clicking in a button from the first page. You can do it like this:

```js
function sendData(url, data) {
  window.location = url + "#" + JSON.stringify(data);
}


function getData() {
  if (window.location.hash == "")
    return "";
  try {
    return JSON.parse(window.location.hash.substr(1));
  } catch {
    return "";
  }
}
```

And you can use these two functions like this:

```html
<button onclick="sendData("page.html", [1, 2, 3])">Redirect</button>
```

And you can get the data by calling `getData()` in the second page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array into  `query string`.

This question can help you: [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

You can put the arry into query string in a.html when you go to b.html using `beforeunload` event, then you get this array in b.html using `DOMContentLoaded` event.