# How to filter records by using Airtable API in Shortcuts app

Tags: shortcut, airtable

In Shortcuts app, I can't filter the records with the 'fields' parameter in the Airtable.

Firstly, I can list the records with the 'maxRecords' parameter in following URL in the Shortcuts app successfully.

```
https://api.airtable.com/v0/<Base>/<Table>?maxRecords=3
```

However, if I use the 'fields' parameter, and change the URL as below.I get the following error messages. I have read the API documentation for several times, but just can't figure it out.

```
https://api.airtable.com/v0/<Base>/<Table>?fields=['Name']

{"error":{"type":"INVALID_REQUEST_UNKNOWN","message":"Invalid request: parameter validation failed. Check your request data."}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Representing lists in URL parameters is a little odd.  There are [several different ways to manage this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/6288435) but none of them involve using common array notation.

The Airtable API expects the fields parameter to be represented as `fields[]=value` where you repeat that argument for each field you want returned.  For example, if I want to receive the fields "Name" and "Other Name" from my records, I would do:

`https://api.airtable.com/v0/YOUR_BASE_ID/YOUR_TABLE_NAME?fields[]=Name&fields[]=Other+Name`

You can also use the [Airtable API Encoder on Codepen](https://codepen.io/airtable/full/rLKkYB) to validate that you are encoding your data correctly.