# How to code one (RESTful) route with more than one parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, routes

My node server uses one and only one route: GET /I/want/title
This route expects a list of websites addresses in query string format e.g.

```
    /web/=http://bing.com
    /web/?address=http://yahoo.com
```

This works ok, so how to use one route for both or more?

```
    yahoo&bing
```

Only one route will be used for both single and multiple requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use, for example:

```
/I/want/title/?address=bing.com,www.yahoo.com
```

And then easily split parameter to array:

```
var addressesArray = address.split(',');
```