# Collection always null when using [FromForm] attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to post `FormData` including both a `File` and a `Collection`.

This is my Model:

```
public class Content
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
public class Model
{
    public IEnumerable<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

This is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task InsertAsync([FromForm]Model dataPost)
{
    await _services.Create(dataPost);
}
```

My `FormData` in JavaScript is:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("File", myFile, "image.jpg")
formData.append("Contents", arrayOfContent)
```

And here is the `header`:

```
'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`
```

The "File" is working fine, but the "Content" is always null.

Where am I going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I have the exact same one, only that the accepted answer didn't help me solve it. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For test I used the following `arrayOfContent`:

```
var arrayOfContent = [];
arrayOfContent.push({ name: 'test', link: 'test.com' });
arrayOfContent.push({ name: 'test2', link: 'test2.com' });
```

And I used a for loop to append the array to the form data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfContent.length; i++) {
    formData.append("Contents[" + i + "].Name", arrayOfContent[i].name);
    formData.append("Contents[" + i + "].Link", arrayOfContent[i].link);
}
```

And I in Visual Studio I can see that it can bind it:

[image]

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string I wrote my answer based on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your array to JSON string in ajax submit code like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("File", myFile, "image.jpg")
formData.append("Contents",  JSON.stringify(arrayOfContent))
```

Then deserialize in your controller