# WooCommerce rest api include parameter not fetching variation with variable product

Tags: rest, api, woocommerce, include

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/10 product type=variable and it is working fine

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/11 product type=variation and it is working fine

But it fetch only one product (with id 10) using include parameter like

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?include=10,11

I need help so that i can fetch 2 or more products (any type) in one API call

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but maybe someone has the same problem still

The include parameter should be array and as this thread explains [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

you should send your parameters as this

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?include[]=10&include[]=11
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to retrieve all the products in woo commerce. If try with this call " /wp-json/wc/v3/products"

Comment: No, i don't want to retrieve all the products. Actually i have a cart with simple product ids and variation ids and i want to retrieve all those products with one API call using include parameter. But include parameter is fetching only products and not variations

Comment: I think Woo commerce API doesn't support that because variations can only retrieved with their parent ID's. You can check this API calls for retrieving variations "/wp-json/wc/v3/products/<product_id>/variations". We can't retrieve simple and variations in one call.

Comment: No, variation can also be retrieved using "/wp-json/wc/v3/products/<variation_id>