# send angularjs array on GET method

Tags: php, angularjs

i have  angularjs array with objects, for exampe:

```
names=[
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]
```

i want to create link that send the array with GET method, something like:

mysite.php?names=[{name,country}]

is it possible?

Comment: You're likely looking for the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that just make sure you URL encode it first: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
and depending on your backend you might have to decode it.

Also, remember from a security perspective you may want to send this in the body because it's much easier for a user to manipulate the URL params.  hope this helps!