# Is there a standardized way to send an array with either 0 or 1 element using `x-www-form-urlencoded` body in an HTTP POST request?

Tags: forms, http, https, form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded

When sending an HTTP request with form values in `x-www-form-url-encoded`, it becomes a simple key-pair string separated by `&` characters.

So sending a form like this:

```
foo: bar
apple: red
```

Will result in the following string:

```
foo=bar&apple=red
```

Usually when sending an array, we use the same key, like this:

```
colors: [red, blue, green]
```

Becomes

```
colors=red&colors=blue&colors=green
```

But when an API expects an array in a request using this body and this type of data, is there a standard way of declaring that a property is an array with only one element, or with 0 elements?

Like this:

```
foo: [bar]
```

Or

```
thingsJonSnowKnows: []
```

Comment: why would you pass the array at all if its zero elements?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a separate key-value pair to store size.
also, see [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)
a possible solution is a comma-delimited value for array

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your definition of standard, but there is a very common format, that's supported by quite a few different frameworks and languages. Creating an array with 1 item looks like this:

```
foo[]=bar
```

I don't think it's possible expressing an empty array, but you can create objects with this.

I believe this syntax originates from PHP, but I've seen this in Java and Javascript frameworks as well. I couldn't find an clear specification describing this exact format in the PHP docs.