# File upload with data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to send file with params (using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to my ASP.NET server, but it gives me only the last value of `arr`.

```js
arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  url: '/Upload?arr=' + arr+ ''
});
```

How can I send more than the last value?

Comment: Maybe send them as: `'/Upload?' + arr.map(e => 'arr[]=' + e).join('&')`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/1762224

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl doesnt woking
but '/Upload?arr=' + arr.map(e => e).join(',') seems good

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because concatenating an array onto a string coerces it into a string joined by commas by default. What you have in necessary because the `map` call is self-returning... It's effectively `arr.join(',')` with extra steps. If what you say above works then I do not see how your original code does not work.