# How to pass parameters as array in API call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api

In my API call, I want to pass range parameters as arrays like this:
[image]

This is how I am trying to pass this array to the API:

```
if (this.price_filter_value = 'Under Rs. 1 Lakh') {
  // this.final_price[0] = [0, 10000];
  // this.final_price[1] = [0, 200000]
  this.final_price = [[0, 10000], [0, 200000]];
}
this.getPortfolioList(this.space_filter_value, this.lifeStage_filter_value, this.theme_filter_value, this.final_price, this.current_page, this.per_page, this.serachedspace);
```

}

But the API is price range is getting called like this not in array.

[image]

Please tell me a approach so that i can pass range as array in Api.

Comment: For an array I believe the the range parameters (plural) should be `range[0][0]=0&range[0][1]=10000&range[1][0]=0&range[1][1]=200000`

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: use `JSON.stringfy(array)` to pass the value in API and `JSON.parse(array_string)` to get the value back

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: Please replace images-of-text with text, as mentioned in [ask], for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).