# How to send list as parameter for search in angular service to .net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, http, service

Please Help me I need to retrieve a list of details using a list of parameters. How to achieve that from angular 10 and .net Core?

Also, Single Entries is working for search. But If I try to enter a second entry in the input field and tried to search it is not working.

The method name is `GetPodForwardings`.

[image: 1]

This is the Method in angular (Service)

```
GetPodForwardings(conNo,newPage,pageSize)
{
    return this.http.get(`${this.BaseUrl}Pod/GetConsignmentList?conNo=${conNo}&newPage=${newPage}&pageSize=${pageSize}`)
  }
```

In .NET Controller

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("GetConsignmentList")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetListofConsignments([FromQuery]List<long> conNo,int currentPage,int pageSize)
{
    return await ProcessQuery(new GetListofConsignmentByConsignmentNoQuery(conNo,currentPage,pageSize));
}
```

Comment: If you are sending a list of things, you should probably be POSTing them rather than GET.

Comment: Can you share your angular component please?

Comment: If the need to cancel the request if there is a new input entered ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of adding parameters to an url in Angular is to use the second `options` parameter of the `http.get("url",options)` function. Unfortunatly they don't accept arrays rightaway (there is an open [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19071)).

However string interpolation like you did should also work. You seem to just have the wrong format. As this is treated very framework specific look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/11126895) to get the right format for your case.