# Possible to map several request properties to same query parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc

So I'm using Spring Boot in Java to write my API. I have a request coming in as such and (NOTE: there will be an indeterminate number of fields coming in, so this may be 100 to where a "field99=test99" will be part of the request):

```
www.example.com/api/examples?field=test&field1=test1&field2=test2
```

All of my request properties will have the name "field" in it, but I have no clue what number will be in the suffix. I currently have in my API the following parameter:

```
@RequestParam(value = "field", required = false) List<String> fields
```

Is there a wildcard matching situation that I could utilize here to make this work? It seems way too tedious/unrealistic to create 100 parameters called String field, String field1, String field2... How would I go about solving this problem so that all the request properties' values end up in my fields list (test, test1, test2, ...)?

Comment: There is some useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best will be to map all request parameters to a Map and then parse the keys for your prefix:

```
@GetMapping("/examples")
@ResponseBody
public String examples(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
    for(Object key : allParams.keySet()) {
        if (key.toString().matches("field[0-9]*")) {
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param#mapping-all-parameters

Comment: Would this still work if I had other request parameters not named field?

Comment: At least for Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE, I can tell you: yes.