# Laravel 8 multi value select filtering

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to build Laravel project that will have a multi-select dropdown with list of categories. Selecting category should reload the page and apply filter.
"scopeFilter" in my model is actually doing filtering, but here i just need to find a way to properly form URL. The problem is that this code i have:

```
<form id="cats-form" action="#" method="GET">
<select multiple class="chosen-select" name="test[]">
    @foreach($categories->get() as $cat) //this loop goes through existing categories in the system
        @php
            //if category is part of URL, pre-select it in the select:
            $arr = request()->all();
            $selected = '';
            if(array_key_exists('test', $arr)) {
                $testArr = $arr['test'];
                $selected = in_array($cat->id, explode(',', $testArr)) ? 'selected' : '';
            }
        @endphp
        <option {{ $selected }} value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</form>

    <script>
        $(".chosen-select").chosen({ })
    
        $('.chosen-select').on('change', function(evt, params) {
            $('#cats-form').submit();
        });
    </script>
```

Is actually giving me this URL:

```
http://localhost:11089/?test%5B%5D=19&test%5B%5D=5
```

While i actually need this:

```
http://localhost:11089/?test=19,5
```

I guess it's a trivial problem to solve for someone with better knowledge of Laravel, can you tell me pls what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is rather how the language or framework or library reads an URL query string. Assuming that your prefered way of URL string is a valid format (as I usually see the format `?arr[]=val1&arr[]=val2` and never see the second format that you preferred), both query string formats should be acceptable to PHP.

As [Yarin stated that the best way PHP reads an array is the first method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top), you don't have to worry too much because the decoded URL query string is exactly in the first format.

Comment: It turns out Laravel 8 understands url perfectly and doing "request()->all()["test"]" would return the data i needed in form of an array :)

Comment: You may also use the query() function of an request object to retrieve input from query string. See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input