# What is the proper way of parsing query parameters using nestJS?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, fastify

Let's say we make the following `GET` API call to our REST API running with NestJS (and fastify):

```
http://localhost:5000/api/test?arrayParam=["abc","def"]&anotherParam="value"
```

Without parsing anything, the query object on the backend looks like this:

```
{
  arrayParam: '["abc","def"]',
  anotherParam: '"value"'
}
```

We can see that parameter values are strings, but in the case of `arrayParam` we would obviously like to work with the actual array.

I come from an expressJS background, and coming from there, there are a couple of approaches. First would be just using a JSON parser middleware, like body-parser. Or just using `JSON.parse()`.

But what is the "proper", NestJS approach? I thought about using type decorators defined in a DTO, and assumed they would be automatically parsed to the type that I defined. But that doesn't work like I assumed it would.

I defined it like this:

```
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  arrayParam?: string[];
```

But validation fails, since `arrayParam` is a string and not an array. So I assume this is not the correct approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending it incorrectly

```
http://localhost:5000/api/test?arrayParam[]=abc&arrayParam[]=def&anotherParam
```

Comment: Incorrectly according to nestJS standards? Or REST standards? I might have just learned bad habits, but I want to know, why is it wrong in this case?

Comment: I didn't ever see a query string like yours. I've seen only two types supported by express that nest uses internally which is `arrayParam[]=abc&arrayParam[]=def` and `arrayParam=abc&arrayParam=def`. Maybe your style is fine too, but as you can see nest doesn't understand it by default.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: Ok thanks, but in case I use the arrayParam[] notation, the query parameter I get on the backend is arrayParam[] instead of arrayParam which I define in a DTO. Is there a good way to avoid this?