# html form with get method is creating multiple query parameters for the same input array

Tags: html, forms, encoding, urlencode

Let's say I have this simple form:

```
<form action="/search/" method="get" role="search">
    <input name="cars[]" value="saab">
    <input name="cars[]" value="honda">
    <input name="cars[]" value="toyota">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

After clicking submit I am being redirected to the search results page and the URL looks like this:
**https://example.com/search/?cars=saab%5B%5D&cars=honda%5B%5D&cars=toyota**

Questions:

1. Why is this piece of code `%5B%5D` added to the url and can I get rid of it?
2. Why is cars appearing multiple times? Can I simple have `?cars=saab,honda,toyota`?

Thanks

Comment: the `%5B%5D` are the urlencoded characters `[]`. Are you sure that is the exact URL you get? Let me test.

Comment: Ah, no the URL is your question isn't actually what you get. Please check it more carefully. The URL I see is: `test.html?cars[]=saab&cars[]=honda&cars[]=toyota`.

Comment: you should remove the brackets from the variable name - i.e. `[]` - that's the variable name, not the type.

Comment: Hey, removing the `[]` from the input name indeed removed that `%5B%5D` urlencoded part, however, now php `$_GET` is only showing the first variable and the variables in the query parameter appear without the `[]` part.
This still doesn't solve the multiple query parameters with the same name though.
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Ah, on the PHP side, the recommended way is to add the brackets to the name.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547490/600486 - keep in mind that this seems limited to PHP (i.e. using brackets in variable names to auto-converted into arrays in the backend)

Comment: You've added PHP to your tags, but there's nothing relating to PHP in your question? My guess is that that's where the problems start.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware As it happens, I am using PHP to pull the query string data but this have nothing to do with the behavior I talked about, try to create to HTML files and see for yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Each input must have a unique name, just change names.

Comment: This is not true if you plan on sending multipe values (i.e. an array of values) for the same variable name