# How to pass a GET parameter in Django in UTF-8

Tags: python, django, web, utf-8, get

I want to pass a GET parameter when rendering a view in Django. My code is as follows :

```
class CustomerList(ListView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'management/customer_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        search_text = request.GET.get('search_text', '') # check if search_text exists
        query = Q(name__icontains=search_text) | Q(phone_number__icontains=search_text)
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(query).order_by('-regdate', '-id')
        if object_list.count() == 0:
            response = redirect('management:customer-create')
            response['Location'] += '?name=%s' % (search_text)
            return response

        context = {
            'object_list':object_list,
            'search_text':search_text,
            'count':self.model.objects.count()
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

and the resulting url goes like this:

`/customer/=?utf-8?b?L2N1c3RvbWVyL2NyZWF0ZS8/bmFtZT3tmY3quLjrj5k=?=`

with page not found error

What do you think am I doing wrong?

Comment: url seems to be incorrect , it should be like -
/customer/?search_text='<search text >' , or can you please elaborate what does your url meant(i mean the url parameters ) .

Comment: @anoop when the user try to search something, the parameter goes like `?search_text='<search_text>'` like you mentioned... it goes well when the search text is in English but not other languages..

it is designed like this : when the user try to search a customer and there is no one with the name, it goes to a 'customer create view'

Comment: you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060940/append-a-querystring-to-url-in-django . Django also gives us funcitonality to mention query params in tuple of **url** ( urls.py ) if still not solves your problem , can you please share django url for **management:customer-create**

Comment: @anoop Oh that was the solution I wanted! I used QueryDict and urlencode and now it works fine. Thanks a million!

Comment: good to hear that.. you can upvote it if you like it.. :)

Comment: @anoop I should come back and upvote when I get 15+ reputation haha.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the comment I found the solution, which was to use urlencode().

```
if object_list.count() == 0:
    from django.http import QueryDict
    response = redirect('management:customer-create')
    q = QueryDict(mutable=True)
    q['name'] = search_text
    query_string = q.urlencode() # encodes utf8 string also
    response['Location'] += '?%s' % (query_string)
    return response
```